# Parsing XML with element tree

Tags: python, xml, suds

I'm trying to parse XML with ElementTree, but I get this error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect
```

My file.py:

```
from suds.client import Client
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(url)
weather = client.service.GetWeather('Sao Paulo', 'Brazil')
print weather

parseWeather = ET.fromstring(weather) # >>>> Here I got my problem!
```

When I try to parse my xml from string weather. Anyone know how to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `weather` response is **not** a string:

```
>>> type(weather)
<class 'suds.sax.text.Text'>
```

but ElementTree will turn it into text. The claimed encoding is UTF16 however:

```
>>> weather.splitlines()[0]
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>'
```

Turn this response into text by  explicitly encoding it to UTF-16:

```
>>> weather = weather.encode('utf16')
>>> parseWeather = ET.fromstring(weather)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can't be sure of the encoding a file *should* be, I tried changing the xml encoding declaration to utf-8 and ElementTree was able to parse it.

```
weather = client.service.GetWeather('Sao Paulo', 'Brazil')
weather = weather.replace('encoding="utf-16"?', 'encoding="utf-8"?')
```

Comment: It looks the replace() method turned `weather` into a string. Martijn has the correct answer.